# How to integrate pig with cassandra on hadoop 2.2.0?

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig

i am getting the following error,when i going to insert the data into cassandra using pig,

ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. 
Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected

My pig script is,

STORE insertformat INTO
       'cql://cql3ks/simple_table1?output_query=UPDATE+cql3ks.simple_table1+set+b+%3D+%3F'
       USING CqlStorage;

Comment: which version of pig are you using?

Comment: Hi nirmal thanks for reply,i am using pig-0.20.0 and cassandra-1.2.15

Comment: pig latest version is 0.16.0. how did you check pig version?

Comment: sorry it's my mistake.I am using pig-0.12.0 version

Comment: try "pig --version" in command line

Comment: I tried that,it gives Apache Pig version 0.12.1-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0):

check this link https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/start.html#req for hadoop supported version of pig.

it seems for pig 0.12.0 -> Hadoop 0.20.2, 020.203, 020.204, 0.20.205, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, or 0.23.0, 0.23.1

for pig 0.14.x -> Hadoop 0.23.X, 1.X or 2.X https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/start.html#req

Comment: I am using Hadoop 2.2.0.so which version of pig is suitable for hadoop-2.2.0

Comment: Pig-0.14.0 is not available in pig site.Only 15 and 16 are available.can you please send the download link for pig.14?

Comment: you can try 0.14+

Comment: before move the data pig into cassandra,can i start the Hadoop?

Comment: starting hadoop services?

Comment: No im not starting the hadoop services.

Comment: what i put in the PIG_CLASSPATH?